# Debug a Homebrew script with pry

Tags: ruby, homebrew, pry

`gem list` shows:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.5)
coderay (1.0.8)
method_source (0.8.1)
pry (0.9.10)
slop (3.3.3)
```

Yet, it seems that if I go into any Homebrew file, and do:

```
require 'pry'
```

I get:

```
Error: no such file to load -- pry
Please report this bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:2:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:2
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:1:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:1
/usr/local/bin/brew:51:in `require'
/usr/local/bin/brew:51:in `require?'
/usr/local/bin/brew:93
```

Even if I try to use a hard coded path, I get:

```
Error: no such file to load -- /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/pry
```

even though it most certainly is there...

```
patrick@vincent:/usr/local/Library/Homebrew(master)>ls -l /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/pry
-rwxr-xr-x  1 patrick  staff  480 Oct 23 02:32 /Users/patrick/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/pry
```

I can go into `irb` and do `require 'pry'` and it works just fine. What’s going on?

Comment: I haven’t gotten to the bottom of this yet, but I think it’s because Homebrew [forces use of your system Ruby](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/f244281d4bae70296fb3bd5949bf03a36833a2ce/bin/brew#L36-L44) instead of your `rvm`/[`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)/other Ruby. Therefore your gems in `~/.rvm/gems/` aren’t found.

Answer (score 0):

aha.. I needed to require 'rubygems'